# Feed new 200A panel from top or bottom?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I'm planning to upgrade my panel and service from 100A to 200A. I have an underground utility feed going into a 200A meter pan, this feeds a second meter pan with a Tesla Backup Switch with a 4/0 - 4/0 - 4/0 Al SEU cable. Currently the feeder from this second meter pan to my main panel is 2-2-2 Al SEU cable, I'm planning to upgrade this to 4/0 Al. Is there any reason not to use 4/0 4/0 4/0 Al SEU cable for this as well? This would have two phase conductors an a concentric neutral. The cable is 1.5" wide (and 0.9" thick), so a lot less bulky than 2" Schedule 40 PVC.

My question is about the orientation of the new main panel. My feeder is currently coming from the bottom, almost all my circuits are coming from the attic above it. The only exception is a 3/4" LB at the center top of the panel with four #6 conductors which is the PV/battery feed. This LB is coming into the back of the panel. It currently is connected as a line-side tap, but I plan to put it on its own 50A breaker (the bus of the new panel is rated at 225A, so no issue with the 120% rule).  The solar LB is 26" above where the 2-2-2 SEU cable goes through the wall. There is also a circuit for the pool that leaves the panel from the back and has 1/2" PVC going down on the exterior (with the rusty 1-hole strap in the pictures), but that is fairly easy to re-locate.

I'm trying to figure out at what height to install the panel, and which brand of panel. I'm leaning towards the Leviton panel, and not inverting it. This means I have to run the feeders from the bottom to the top along the sides, but if gives me more space at the top for all the NM coming in as well as the PV feedthrough. I would have to change the 3/4" EMT on the outside because I think I will have to come into the panel much higher. Since the Leviton panel has each hot and neutral wired right underneath the breaker I might have to extend some neutrals in case they have been cut short. I'm assuming mounting the panel high (6'7" to top breaker) would be good because it would give me the most amount of wire to work with. Both panels have 42 spaces.

Would love to hear your thoughts and advice on this.
With the QO panel, it seems like I could invert it, and put the main breaker at the bottom, and still have space at the top for the PV feedthrough.

I'm on the 2017 NEC, and not required to install an exterior service disconnect.
[image: Meter layout outside]
[image: old main panel inside]
[image: Leviton panel layout]
[image: Square D QO panel layout]

Comment: I happen to favor inverting, regardless, so long as the panel is correctly labelled to support it. But it's mostly a matter of opinion. Recall that the "extra space" you think you get has a significant amount taken up by the feeders, and you have a lot of space on one side of the panel taken up with feeders if coming in the bottom and up inside the panel. Bottom feed/bottom main the feeder conductors are completely out of your way. There's plenty of room in the non-feeder-end of the Leviton to get the conductors in and off to each side.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to keep the meter-mounted Tesla Backup Switch instead of converting to a more conventional setup?

Comment: Coming in from the bottom pretty much eliminates the potential for rainwater intrusion into your panel along the path of the feeders.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Ideally I would have preferred to have the Tesla Backup Switch mounted with the PSE&G meter on top of it (like a collar), but PSE&G does not approve that. The Backup Switch was just installed by Tesla, and allows me to do the work on the new panel without have to make terminations that are live, once I pull the meter. That is why I'm thinking of only replacing the feeder from the Backup Switch and replacing the main panel inside

Comment: @Huesmann sorry, I should have been clearer. The feed will come into the bottom of the panel in either scenario, the question was if I should run the feeders inside the panel to the top where the main breaker is, or invert the panel. The panel is inside.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yes, both panels are support inverting, and the main breakers actuate side-to-side, so no issue with that. Thanks, I'll see if it possible to have the feeders come in through the existing hole in the wall into the back of the panel, might be tricky with the bending radius of 4/0 Al.